# Dereferencing a variable to its value to use in another function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashtable

```
function get_event_ids_from_dom()
{
    var event_ids = {};
    $.each(
    $("td.ms-cal-defaultbgcolor a"),
        function(index,value){
             var str = new String(value); 
             var id = str.substring(str.indexOf('=')+1,str.length);
             if(typeof(event_ids[id]) == "undefined")
             {
                event_ids[id] = this;
            }
            else
            {
                **event_ids.id.push(this);**

            }
        }
     )
        return event_ids;
}
```

In above javascript event_ids is a hashtable. I am trying to assign values to this hashtable.

A hashtable can be added with multiple values using "hashtable.key.push(value)". I am trying to do this using event_ids.id.push(this); in the above code.

I have declared "id" as a variable in the code. The problem is, I am not able to dereference variable "id" to its value.

Is this possible in jquery/javascript?

Example use of hashtable:

```
event_ids = {};
event_ids["1"]= 'John';
event_ids.1.push('Julie');
```

The above example would add john and julie to hash table.

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov No it does not work. I am getting TypeError: event_ids[id].push is not a function, In firebug. Could you please check again?

Comment: Your example is not valid JavaScript: `**event_ids.id.push(this);**` ? And you shouldn't use the `String` class directly. It's just there to decorate string values with methods. When you call methods on a string value JavaScript is simply calling the methods on the prototype of `String` in the context of the string value. You're going to run into problems if you're using an object as a string instead of just a string.

Comment: @apphacker The value variable will have something like this "Business%20Development/Lists/Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=907". But it is in object form. I want to convert it into string to process it. Is it possible without using String class?

Comment: @apphacker got it from Ivaylo's answer. changed my code to value.toString() , Thanks for the info :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function get_event_ids_from_dom() {
    var event_ids = {};
    $.each(
        $("td.ms-cal-defaultbgcolor a"),
        function(index,value){
            var str = value.toString(); 
            var id = str.substring((str.indexOf('=') + 1), str.length);
            if(typeof(event_ids[id]) == "undefined") {
                event_ids[id] = [];
            }
            event_ids[id].push(this);
        });
    return event_ids;
}
```

Please, note that while `object["id"]` is the same as `object.id`, `object[id]` is not.

Comment: You should accept his answer if you like it. Also Ivaylo I can't vote up your answer until you get rid of that `String` use. :P

Comment: @apphacker, thanks for pointing out, it was a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 2):

Nicola almost had it:

```
if(typeof(event_ids[id]) == "undefined") {
  event_ids[id] = [];
}
event_ids[id].push(this);
```

Also please read the comment I left for your question.

Comment: yes, stupid error i made. I corrected it. I think in his question he was trying to put bold around the line.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion event_ids is an object (there are no hastables in javascript, just either  **indexed arrays** or **objects**). 
What you are tring to do is using push (an array method) on something that is not an array so i think you must change something:

you could try:

```
         if(typeof(event_ids[id]) == "undefined")
         {
            event_ids[id] = [];// the property id of object event_ids is an array
            event_ids[id].push(this);
        }
        else
        {
            event_ids[id].push(this);

        }
```

It should work

Comment: `event_ids[id][] = this;` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: The else statement is totally unnecessary.

Comment: i didn't want to copy your answer! :) i just put correct code inside, it sure is unneccessary